# How to add service names to database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have interface

```
public interface ISocialService
    {
        //...
    }
```

and class

```
public class RedditService : ISocialService
{

        private readonly DbContext _context;

        public RedditService(DbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
}
```

I also have few other services implementing IRedditService.

This is my DbContext:

```
public class DbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {

        private readonly IEnumerable<ISocialService> _socialServices;
        public DbContext(DbContextOptions<CrastinatorContext> options, IEnumerable<ISocialService> socialServices) : base(options)
        {
            _socialServices = socialServices;
        }
        //...

        public DbSet<SiteName> SiteNames { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            //...
            foreach (var site in socialservices)
            {
                builder.Entity<SiteName>()
                    .HasData(new { Name = site.GetType().Name });

            }

        }
```

But I can't do this because SocialServices have dbcontext injected to constructor, so I cant inject socialservices to dbcontext. (circular dependency)
The reason why I want to add Method names to db:

I want to send data to user from specific services.
For example if User has RedditService preference then send him data from RedditService, if user has ServiceA, ServiceB,
then send data from ServiceA and ServiceB and so on.

So I wanted to store these services names in database.
Then in controller I would check user preferences: if(user has serviceA) then send data from serviceA.

Is there another way to achieve that?

TLDR: I want to add MethodNames to SiteNames table but I don't know WHERE should I do it.

Comment: and why you wana have different tables for different services? instead having one Service table with FK to ServiceName ?

Comment: @Selvin I want to have "ServiceA" and "ServiceB" in ServiceNames table. My question is: how do I add it on app startup?

Comment: by adding it independly from what is inside `ServiceName` ... dynamic tables are almost always terrible idea

Comment: @Selvin I've come up with this idea because I want to send data to user from specific services. For example if User has ServiceA preference then send him data from ServiceA, if user has ServiceA, ServiceB, then send data from ServiceA and ServiceB and so on. So I wanted to store these services names in database. Then in controller I would check user preferences: if(user has serviceA) then send data from serviceA. But for this I would need to store this service names in database.

Comment: as I wrote use one Services table and select only with given ServiceID and UserID ... ServiceID should be FK to ID in ServiceNames ... there is no need for different tables

Comment: Sure, now I understand that, but my question is: where do I add data to ServiceNames? For example I would have this entity in ServiceNames: ID:1, Name: ServiceA.
But where in code do I add this data?

Comment: `Autofac` can resolve circular dependencies using property injection. https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/circular-dependencies.html

Comment: See also: http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/01/circular-dependency-in-constructors-and-dependency-injection/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all implementations of the `ISocialService` by reflection, so this way there is no need to inject them into the DbContext. Here's a sample.

```
public interface ISocialService { }
public class FacebookService : ISocialService { }
public class RedditService : ISocialService { }

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var socialServices = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
            .Where(p => typeof(ISocialService).IsAssignableFrom(p) && p.IsClass);

        foreach (var t in socialServices)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(t.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I suggest redesigning the app a little bit. Otherwise, every time you add a new implementation of `ISocialService` or rename any existing one, you'll need to reseed the database. I would be cautious with such couplings.

Comment: Op is using dependency injection; I don't think there's an issue with how the DI container finds the services, the issue is the circular dependency.

Comment: @IanMercer Yeah, but he's using DI in the DbContext just to get names of types that are implementing ISocialService. I'm proposing doing that by reflection so there is no need to inject them. I will update my answer to make it clear, thanks!

Comment: Thank you for answer, would you suggest adding available services to DB manually? Or my approach to this problem is completely wrong?